# How to migrate from singleton pattern to Spring?

Tags: spring, singleton

I am currently working on a large non-Spring codebase.
I'd like to introduce Spring Context into the codebase, but I want to do this gradually.

One of the first challenges I'd like to tackle is to "Springify" a large singleton object that is used quite a lot in the code.

The singleton is used in the code like this:

```
SomeInstance instance = SomeInstance.getInstance();
instance.doSomething()
```

The singleton object contains a field and method like this:

```
class SomeInstance {
    private static SomeInstance instance;

    public static SomeInstance getInstance(){
    if(instance == null){
        instance = new SomeInstance();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Ok this works, but I'd like to make the `SomeInstance` class a Spring bean.

No problem:

```
@Component
class SomeInstance {
    ...
}
```

However I'd still like to keep the `getInstance()` static method, and make it return the singleton instance in order to be backward compatible and not have to refactor everything.
If I want to get rid of the `getInstance()` method everywhere in the code, this means a HUGE refactoring:

- make all objects that use `SomeInstance` Spring beans
- use @Autowired to wire in the singleton

That would be great, but I just can't justify a big refactoring like that right now.

But how can I make `SomeInstance` Spring-managed and still keep the `getInstance()` method for backwards compatibility?

I thought about something like this:

```
public static SomeInstance getInstance() {
    return ApplicationContext.getBean("someInstanceBean");
}
```

However the `getBean()` method may not be called from a static context ...

Any ideas on how to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In you application context XML file, all you need to do is write entries like the following:

```
<bean id="thing" name="thing" class="com.example.ThingSingleton"
    factory-method="getInstance">
</bean>
```

There is no reason to change your existing API. Your existing API enforces that what claims or is specified to be a singleton is in fact a singleton. That is good, and worth keeping. Spring is meant to be a convenient way of wiring together POJOs, using the Plain Old Java API of classes, not an alternative to constructors, factory methods, etc.

Once you have done that, you might say to yourself "none of my code should ever call `com.example.ThingSingleton.getInstance()`, so I should mark it as `@Deprecated`, it being a relic of a time before I used Spring". But this would be quite wrong. The method is not at all *deprecated* in any real sense: you are explicitly telling Spring to use it and that is not a mistake. That method is still the one and only approved manner of getting an instance of the Singleton. It *just so happens* that no code *you* write calls it. *Deprecated* does not mean "unused in my code". It means "should not be used because likely to be removed in the future". You won't be deleting that `getInstance()` method, will you?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a singleton to hold the context.  Something like this would probably work for you.
The ApplicationContext will be set automatically during startup due to the ApplicationContextAware interface.

There is a possibility that context will be null that you may want to mitigate, but if Spring is initialized properly that should not be an issue.

```
@Component
public class TestClass implements ApplicationContextAware {


    private static ApplicationContext context = null;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        context = applicationContext;
    }

    public static  Object getBean(String beanName){
        return context.getBean(beanName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I was just cursing on that this morning.
The context being `null` was a big problem (because apparently Spring loads asynchronous).
I tried using a lock / condition to make threads wait for the applicationContext, but my knowledge of Java concurrency obviously did not suffice (damn you IllegalMonitorStateException!).
In the end I could mitigate the problem, but I don't think this is waterproof...